# How to console the JSON.Stringify result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<script>
    $.getJSON('url/rest/1', function (data) {           
        var mydata = JSON.stringify(data);  
    });
</script>
```

This is my code. For console.log(mydata) my output is :

```
{  
   "data":[  
      {  
         "orderid":"9",
         "ordercode":"TTG-13-06-3"
      },
      {  
         "orderid":"12",
         "ordercode":"TTG-13-06-4"
      },
      {  
         "orderid":"15",
         "ordercode":"TTG-13-06-5"
      },
      {  
         "orderid":"20",
         "ordercode":"TTG-13-06-6"
      },
      {  
         "orderid":"24",
         "ordercode":"TTG-13-06-7"
      },
      {  
         "orderid":"26",
         "ordercode":"TTG-13-06-8"
      },
      {  
         "orderid":"31",
         "ordercode":"TTG-13-06-9"
      },
      {  
         "orderid":"36",
         "ordercode":"TTG-13-06-10"
      },
      {  
         "orderid":"41",
         "ordercode":"TTG-13-06-11"
      },
      {  
         "orderid":"44",
         "ordercode":"TTG-13-06-12"
      }
   ],
   "status":"success"
}
```

I need to get ordercode alone in console. How can I achive it?

Comment: each of ordercode ??.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `$.map` to transform each object in your collection:

```
var orderCodes = $.map(data.data, function(entry){
  return entry.ordercode;
});
```

and get an array of all ordercodes.

See: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/

If you're using any sort of functional programming library (i.e. `underscore`) this operation is usually abstracted into a method called `pluck`: http://underscorejs.org/#pluck

Answer (score 0):

Use [each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) of jQuery

```
$.each(data.data,function(index,value){
       console.log(value.overcode)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The return data is array of objects, thus we need to loop through it to retrieve ordercode property.

```
var mydata = JSON.stringify(data); 

// Check if mydata object has "data" property before looping
if(mydata.hasOwnProperty(data)) {
  for(var i = 0; i < mydata.data.length; i++) {
    console.log(mydata.data[i].ordercode);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(myData.data, function (i, obj) {
    console.log(obj.ordercode);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First option -

```
var parsedMyData = JSON.parse(mydata);    
var objectForConsole = $.extend({}, $.map(parsedMyData, function(val) {return  val.ordercode;     }));
console.log(objectForConsole);
```

This will print: `Object {0: "TTG-13-06-3", 1: "TTG-13-06-4"....}`

Answer (score 0):

```
Second using foreach-  
var parsedMyData = JSON.parse(mydata);   
var arr = [];         
for(i in parsedMyData)    {    
     arr.push(parsedMyData[i].ordercode);
    }
console.log(arr);
o/p- ["TTG-13-06-3", "TTG-13-06-4", "TTG-13-06-5".....]
```

Answer (score 0):

Best and shortest option-

```
var data=JSON.stringify(mydata);
$.map(data, function(value){
    console.log(value.ordercode);
});
```